# Load two model's weights into one on Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

What I'm trying to do is loading Keras layers' weights from `model A` and `model B`, both with same architecture, to `model C`. Let me explain:

I know that typical way of loading weights is:

```
modelC.load_weights('name.h5')
```

But by doing this you can only load from one model and, as I've said before, I do not want to load all of it. Is there any way you can partially load these weights? If not, how could I solve this?

What I really want would be something like this:

```
modelC_weights = 0.2 * modelA_weights + 0.8 * modelB_weights
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something ugly but that shoud work:

```
modelC.load_weights('name.h5')
weights1 = np.array(modelC.get_weights())

modelC.load_weights('name2.h5')
weights2 = np.array(modelC.get_weights())

modelC.set_weights(0.2 * weights1 + 0.8 * weights2)
```

Comment: `weightsC = [0.2 * w1 + 0.8 * w2 for w1, w2 in zip(weights1, weights2)]`

Comment: Thank you! It works, but I have one question: by multplying it by `0.8` (or any number) aren't you getting other random weights?

Comment: You're getting the same weights multiplied by 0.8.